# Center navbar and add top/bottom-borders

Tags: html, css, wordpress, navbar

I want to center (automatically) the navbar on [this site](http://blueboxluxe.com/). Also, I need to have a 1px border-top and 1px border-bottom that extends roughly 70% of the nav area.

It should look like this mockup once it's done:

[image: screen]

Comment: Fixed embedding image :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the floats on your li tags, and on your #navigation, add `text-align: center;`. Your floats are making your parent have a height of 0, which will in turn not allow you to have your borders. This fixes both those issues. From there, just add `border-top: 1px solid white; border-bottom: 1px solid white;` to your ul to get your lines.

Comment: Also, remove the 100% width on your ul, and set its display to inline-block, so it doesn't fill the whole parent container.

Comment: so close.. Now everything is centered, but, it's not on one line.

Comment: Sorry, add `display:inline-block` to your li tags.

Comment: Ok, last issue is that the lines need to not be 100% width.. They need to terminate with the last menu item. Fixable?

Comment: Yup, that was the first comment. Remove 100% width on the ul, set the display to inline-block.

Comment: I did make that change.. Did I miss something?

Comment: Make the change on #main-nav, the id of the ul.

Comment: `#main-nav { display:inline-block; }`, nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qZTAt/

The key there is this piece of code:

```
nav {
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    margin: 0 15%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't do it automatically.. It's a set margin vs. auto margin.

Comment: What are you looking for then? Do you want the navigation links to be separated evenly with the last one and the first one aligned with the end and start of the border (respectively)?

Comment: @DrDavid have you seen the fiddle?

Comment: huh.. The jsfiddle looks cool.. Might have to play with it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `margin:0 auto; padding:0;`

Comment: But first you need to define a width.  Margin 0 auto will only work for specified with, otherwise the DIV's width is 100% automatically and it's already in the center, so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

Right I'm going to come in late to this party (with an already answered question!) just to add what I would have done.  It's based on this technique [here](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/beautiful-css-centered-menus-no-hacks-full-cross-browser-support)

http://jsfiddle.net/rabmcnab/GSSQx/

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<header>
<h1 class="font"> Heading</h1>
<nav>
<ul>
```

```css
<style> body {
  font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.font {
  font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
}
header {
  background-color: aqua;
  padding: 40px 0px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
nav {
  border-top: thin solid white;
  border-bottom: thin solid white;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -10px;
  color: white;
  font: 40px/0 arial;
  padding: 40px 0;
}
li:hover {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One" rel="stylesheet">

<body>
  <header>
    <h1 class="font"> Heading</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Wedding</li>
        <li>Engagement</li>
        <li>Services</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>



  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

```
    <li>Wedding</li>
    <li>Engagement</li>
    <li>Services</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```